# How to make program to continue running after exception?

Tags: java, loops, exception

How to make program to continue running after exception?

I have this code:

```
this.runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (!isLoading && !playerList.isEmpty()) {
            this.isLoading = true;
            ArrayList<Player> clonedList = (ArrayList<Player>)playerList.clone();
            playerList.clear();
            for (Player player : clonedList) {
                main.getDataManager().loadPlayer(player);
            }
            this.isLoading = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Method "main.getDataManager().loadPlayer(player);" may throw exception.

After exception my infinite loop that executes this runnable's run() method every 5 seconds is stopped. How to make it never stop/exit if exception will be thrown? Is it possible?

Comment: Use a `try`-`catch` block to catch the exception.See : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch the exception:

```
public void run() {
    if (!isLoading && !playerList.isEmpty()) {
        this.isLoading = true;
        ArrayList<Player> clonedList = (ArrayList<Player>)playerList.clone();
        playerList.clear();
        for (Player player : clonedList) {
            try {
                main.getDataManager().loadPlayer(player);
            } catch (Exception e) { }
        }
        this.isLoading = false;
    }
}
```

You can alternatively put the whole `for` loop in the `try`-`catch` block, so that if one player fails to load, it stops trying to load others until `run` is called again.

```
public void run() {
    if (!isLoading && !playerList.isEmpty()) {
        this.isLoading = true;
        ArrayList<Player> clonedList = (ArrayList<Player>)playerList.clone();
        playerList.clear();
        try {
            for (Player player : clonedList) {
                main.getDataManager().loadPlayer(player);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { }
        this.isLoading = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Catch and swallow/handle it:

```
for (Player player : clonedList) {
    try {
       main.getDataManager().loadPlayer(player);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where you need exception handling. If an exception is not handled program stops after the point where exception is thrown. But you can enclose your exception throwing code inside try-catch block like this.

```
for (Player player : clonedList) {
try {
   main.getDataManager().loadPlayer(player);
} catch (Exception e) {
   // your recovery from exception can be done here..
}
```

}
//after this point program can still execute even an exception has been thrown..